# how to replace text in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use vbscript to replace the input, for example the user is entering name in lastname,firstname format, but once he enters I want to print it like hello:firstname lastname

this is what I have so far

```
     strInput = InputBox("Enter name, LastName,FirstName Format")
  WScript.Echo "Hello: " & strInput
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there will be a comma between the last name and first name, you can use the `Split` function to separate the names into an array.

```
a = Split(strInput, ",")
```

Now, `a(0)` is the first element (their last name) and `a(1)` is the second element (their first name).

```
MsgBox "Hello " & a(1) & " " & a(0)
```

Comment: Additionally, in vbscript, you can auto-parse the split command without storing it in a variable by appending the array index directly off of the split(). E.g. `split(strInput, ",")(1) & " " & split(strInput, ",")(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Use Split() on "," to get the parts and re-order:

```
>> inp = "LastName,FirstName"
>> alf = Split(inp, ",")
>> WScript.Echo alf(1), alf(0)
>>
FirstName LastName
```

Depending on the input, you may need to take care of a ", " (blank after comma) first.

A RegExp - as in

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "(\w+),(\w+)"
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace(inp, "$2 $1")
>>
FirstName LastName
```

would make it easier to deal with non-standard input.

To add a 3rd strategy - Instr()/Mid() -

```
>> p = Instr(inp, ",")
>> WScript.Echo Mid(inp, p + 1) & " " & Mid(inp, 1, p - 1)
>>
FirstName LastName
```